# GLTF files in three js

Tags: gltf, three.js

i've been trying to export a gltf file to three js from blender I have used this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@matthewmain/how-to-import-a-3d-blender-object-into-a-three-js-project-as-a-gltf-file-5a67290f65f2) and realised that it may be outdated since the [gltf extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) they're using is archived and it doesn't appear in the group menu in the uv node editor. How do I export a 3d gltf file suitable for three.js in 2.81 version of blender. There seems to be no tutorial on this.
[This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html) is pretty confusing since I have never used blender before only maya.

Comment: While I haven't used three.js, judging by their [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) you should be able to use .gltf and .glb files.

Comment: That last link (to the official [blender addon docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html)) is the right workflow, if you already know the basics of creating materials in Blender. If not, I would start with a tutorial on Blender's Principled BSDF, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5KOdVft93E). If you follow the guidelines in the addon docs, a Principled BSDF material will export to glTF correctly.

Comment: This has been answered in this link [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/dont-know-how-to-create-gltf-file-suitable-for-three-js-in-blender/13065)

Answer (score 1):

That last link (to the [official blender addon docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/import_export/io_scene_gltf2.html)) is the right workflow, if you already know the basics of creating materials in Blender. If not, I would start with a tutorial on Blender's Principled BSDF, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5KOdVft93E). If you follow the guidelines in the addon docs, a Principled BSDF material will export to glTF correctly.

More information in https://discourse.threejs.org/t/dont-know-how-to-create-gltf-file-suitable-for-three-js-in-blender/13065.